# Why does atoi() cause a bus error?

Tags: c, atoi

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    const char* str_int = "777";
    const char* str_float = "333.3";
    int i = atoi(str_int);
    float f = atof(str_float);

    printf("%s %s", i, f); 
}
```

I have tried several bits of example code I‛ve found online, and all of them cause bus errors. Why is this happening?

Comment: Since you mentioned you are new to C.  ISO says main needs a type. Traditionally in C you will declare all variables before making any function calls, before C99 you had to.

Comment: @JoeMcGrath: A function call is permitted in the initializer for an object with automatic storage duration even in C90.

Comment: Figured I would get the "ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code", but you are correct. Ignore my comment. I can't delete it.

Answer (score 5):

Your `printf` is incorrect. Try this instead:

```
printf("%d %f", i, f);
```

The problem is that your format specifiers are `%s`, which expect strings. But you gave it an `int`and a `float`. Therefore the result is undefined behavior.

The reason why it's crashing is because `printf` will try to read the parameters as strings (which are pointers) and deference them as such, but they are invalid pointers.

Here's a reference on `printf` and its format specifiers:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Comment: why did this cause the problem? what exactly do those %letters mean? I'm very very new to c.

Comment: [google's first result for printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: Woah, why the downvote? Is there something wrong with my answer?

Comment: I'm wondering the same things, there's nothing wrong with either of our answers...

Comment: @David: `%d` means *"the next argument is an `int`, please format it as a decimal number"*, and the `%f` means *"the next argument is a `double`, please format it as a decimal number with 6 places after the decimal point"*.  (Note that due to subtle reasons, your `float` is passed to `printf` as a `double`).  `%s` means *"the next argument is a `char *` pointing to a null-terminated string, please format it as a string"*.  The latter causes a problem for you because you lied to `printf` - the next argument *wasn't* a `char *` pointing to a null-terminated string.

Answer (score 3):

Please take the habit of **asking warnings from your compiler**. With `gcc` it is the `-Wall` option and (on Linux/Debian/Sid gcc 4.6) I'm getting with your example file `david.c` using the `gcc -Wall -g -o david david.c`command:

```
david.c:4:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wreturn-type]
david.c: In function 'main':
david.c:11:5: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat]
david.c:11:5: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'double' [-Wformat]
david.c:12:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

A newbie should *correct his code till the compiler gives no more warnings*. There are very very rare cases when leaving a warning is acceptable (it should happen less than once a year for a seasoned C programmer).

Comment: This looks like good advice. does the -wall option turns all the warnings on or just some? can you show your gcc command?

Comment: @David [this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) will tell you more about warning options. An example is `gcc -Wall -o test test.c`.

Comment: I've edited the text to show the command used to compile your david.c file into a david executable. The `-Wall` turns almost all warnings, you could get even more by adding `-Wextra` to it. In your case, adding `-Wextra` don't change the warnings obtained.

Answer (score 2):

It's not, `printf` is. You're telling `printf` that you're passing it two *strings* (`"%s"`), when in fact you're passing an `int` and a `float`. It should be:

```
printf("%d %f", i, f);
```

Otherwise it'll treat the two arguments on the stack as strings (ie. `char*`).

Since two `char*`s haven't been passed as promised, when it tries to print the values of what it thinks are two strings on the stack, it'll cause undefined behaviour and potentially crash. This is most likely because the pointers it's trying to dereference are invalid and don't in fact point to a valid address.

`printf` has no way of telling if the arguments you're passing are correct, your compiler warnings however will. *Turn up your compiler warnings.*

Read here for more about warning options with gcc (if that's what you're using): http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Read here for more about the format specifiers (ie. `%s`, `%d`): http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Comment: And the downvote was for? Same for @Mystical, why was his answer downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Printf is not correct.Change it to

```
 printf("%d,%f",i,f);
```

Refer this link to understand the printf syntax clearly:

http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output